# Flutter enum extends enum

Tags: dart, enums, syntax

I'm facing some issues with creating an error types. For example

```
enum WifiBaseErrors {
wifiNotFound,
permisionMissing,
wifiTurnedOff
}
```

also I'm having functions like `connectToDeviceUsingPin`

this function can return all previously mentioned values but also another errors

```
enum WifiPinCodeConnectionErrors {
wifiNotFound,
permisionMissing,
wifiTurnedOff
wrongPin,
pinTooShort,
}
```

I want to avoid code repetition. In the ideal world it would be

```
enum WifiPinCodeConnectionErrors extends WifiBaseErrors{
wrongPin,
pinTooShort,
}
```

How to achieve this in dart?

Comment: Relevant link for details about why it is not possible to use extends as in the example: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/2733

Comment: You don't.  Enums are all effectively sealed.  You'll need a different strategy.

Answer (score 0):

It won't be a single *enum*, but you can do something like:

```dart
sealed class WifiPinCodeConnectionErrors implements Enum {
  static const wifiNotFound = WifiBaseErrors.wifiNotFound;
  static const permisionMissing= WifiBaseErrors.permisionMissing;
  static const wifiTurnedOff = WifiBaseErrors.wifiTurnedOff;
  static const wrongPin = _WifiPinCodeConnectionErrors.wrongPin;
  static const pinTooShort = _WifiPinCodeConnectionErrors.pinTooShort;
  static const List<WifiPinCodeConnectionErrors> values = [
    wifiNotFound, permisionMissing, wifiTurnedOff, wrongPin, pinTooShort
  ];  
}
  
enum _WifiPinCodeConnectionErrors implements WifiPinCodeConnectionErrors {
  wrongPin,
  pinTooShort,
}

enum WifiBaseErrors implements WifiPinCodeConnectionErrors {
  wifiNotFound,
  permisionMissing,
  wifiTurnedOff,
}
```

The place where this fails to be real enum, is that both `wifiNotFound` and `wrongPin` has `.index` zero.
If that's not a problem for you, it should work.